# Redirect if URL contains String A but not String B

Tags: javascript, redirect

this topic was discussed often here, but I am still not able to find a working solution.

I want to check the URL:

```
If contains String=A, but not String=C redirect to ...
Else if contains String=B, but not String=C redirect to ...
Else if contains String=C redirect to ...
Else redirect to ...
```

My code is:

```
if (
window.location.href.indexOf('String=A') > -1 && !
window.location.href.indexOf('String=C') > -1 ) {
window.location.href = "/subpage/" + document.location.search + '?#onlya';
}
else if (
window.location.href.indexOf('String=B') > -1 && !
window.location.href.indexOf('String=C') > -1 ) {
window.location.href = "/subpage/" + document.location.search + '#onlyb';
}
else if (
window.location.href.indexOf('String=C') > -1 ) {
window.location.href = "/subpage/" + document.location.search + '#containsc';
}
else {
window.location.href = "/subpage/" + document.location.search + '#foundnothing';
}
```

I already tried with

```
window.location.href.indexOf('String=C') != -1
```

and so on..
What actual happens:

- xyz.com?String=A - redirects to '/subpage#onlya' (correct!)
- xyz.com?String=B - redirects to '/subpage#onlyb' (correct!)
- xyz.com?String=C - redirects to '/subpage#containsc' (correct!)
- xyz.com - redirects to '/subpage#foundnothing' (correct!)

but:

- xyz.com?String=A&String=C - redirects to '/subpage#onlya' (but should redirect to '/subpage#containsc'

---

Edited Solution:

```
  if (
    window.location.href.indexOf('String=A') > -1 && !(window.location.href.indexOf('String=C') > -1 )
      ) {
      window.location.href = "/subpage/" + document.location.search + '?#onlya';
  }
  else if (
    window.location.href.indexOf('String=B') > -1 && !(window.location.href.indexOf('String=C') > -1 )
      ) {
      window.location.href = "/subpage/" + document.location.search + '?#onlyb';
  }
  else if (
    window.location.href.indexOf('String=C') > -1
      ) {
      window.location.href = "/subpage/" + document.location.search + '?#containsc';
  }
  else {
      window.location.href = "/subpage/" + document.location.search + '?#foundnothing';
  }
```

Comment: What do u mean with "nothing works" ?

Comment: @schildi edited the infos to the main post

Comment: in case 1: if you enter `window.location.href.indexOf('String=C')` in your console of your page, what does it return?

Comment: ok, maybe I was to dump, but Case 1 und Case 2 are wokrking. But if the URL is xyz.com?String=A&String=C - so case 3 is wrong. I edit the mainpost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` returns the index of the found string or -1 if not found.
when you negate it with ! any number except 0 will result in `false`.

the condition (string is given) `!window.location.href.indexOf('String=C') > -1`
is equivalent to `false > -1` which is `true`

you can get your expected results by wrapping it like:

`!(window.location.href.indexOf('String=C') > -1 )` or by using tilde with double negation
`!!~window.location.href.indexOf('String=C') > -1`

Comment: so you mean window.location.href.indexOf('String=A') > -1
!!~window.location.href.indexOf('String=C') > -1 ) {
window.location.href = "/subpage/" + document.location.search + '?#onlya';
}
? Or is can I combine it?